# float64 not showing decimal points

Tags: go

Why doesn't my `float64` have any decimal points?

I expected `40000/3` should return something like `13333.3333`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var f float64 = 40000 / 3
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/OxjLjwPGYhx

Comment: `var f float64 = 40000 / float64(3)
fmt.Printf("%f", f)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

40000/3 is an integer value. It is then converted to a float. To perform float division use float values. 40000.0/3 will result in a float value.

Comment: More precisely, `40000/3` is an untyped integer constant, not an `int`.

Comment: @jub0bs, 40000/3 is an untyped constant that is evaluated at compile time as an int. The result does not have a decimal part.

Comment: We're on the same page.